# Lookback api: duplicate snapshots are being returned even though compress is set to true

Tags: rally, lookbackapi

I have a request with this `find`:

```
"find":  {
      "Project": 123,
      "_TypeHierarchy": "HierarchicalRequirement",
      "fields": ["FormattedID","ScheduleState"],
      "hydrate": "ScheduleState",
      "compress": true
}
```

and it returns duplicate snapshots, for example:

```
Results: 
[
{
ScheduleState: "Defined",
FormattedID: "US3000"
},
{
ScheduleState: "Defined",
FormattedID: "US3000"
},
{
ScheduleState: "Defined",
FormattedID: "US3000"
},
```

Also tried this endpoint:

```
  https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/100/artifact/snapshot/query.js?find={"Project":123,"_TypeHierarchy":"HierarchicalRequirement"}&fields=["FormattedID","ScheduleState"]&hydrate=["ScheduleState"]&compress=true
```

same duplicates are returned.

Should "compress" option reduce the number of snapshots returned by queries based on changes in the values of the fields that are selected? There were no changes in ScheduleState, as duplicate snapshots show the same "Defined" State. There were other changes to this story US3000, PlanEstimate was changed, but it is not being fetched to affect. Is there a problem with my syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make compress work, you must include _ValidFrom, _ValidTo, and ObjectID in the list of requested fields.  Give that a try.